# Parse key, value from JSON in Redshift

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-redshift, unnest, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a JSON column and values in it look like this :`{"env":"test","app-name":"ap123","product-type":"web-app"}.`
Note that the keys can change, it may have like `{"env1":"test","app-name1":"ap123","product-type1":"web-app"}` in the next row.

I want to select all the keys and values from the JSON column and the results should look like the ones below

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| env | test |
| app-name | ap123 |
| product-type | web-app |
| env | dev |
| env 1 | test |
| app-name 1 | ap123 |

I have already tried using SUPER datatype and f_py_json_keys() function and language plpythonu. None of them are supported with the data I have. Please suggest an alternative method to hack this problem

Comment: The "Object Unpivotting" section of this seems to answer your question : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html

Comment: All of it requires the data type to be 'super', which is not supported in my case

Comment: maybe only plpythonu can help if name of keys is vairable. 
If you know the name of keys, this function can help: `select json_extract_path_text('{"env":"test","app-name":"ap123","product-type":"web-app"}','app-name');`.  documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html